# Script for changing access rights of multiple files and directories?

Tags: 14.04, scripts, chmod

I want to create a script that changes the access rights for all files and folders in a specific directory tree. All users should have read and write access for all files and directories. Does anyone have an idea about such a script can look like?
Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: That should be simple: `chmod a+rw -R $DIRECTORY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a script. Try `sudo chmod 777 -R /folderTreeBeginning` to make /folderTreeBeginning completely world writable, readable, and exectuable. Look under `man chmod` for changing the values of 777 to what you need. Use the `-R` to make the change recursive, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: One further question: I need a script that does the following:
1) find all files in a certain directory (including subdirectories) that do not have write access for all users.
2) Execute command `sudo chmod 777` only for those files.
Could you please send me the code for such a script?
Thank you!